# Adding comments with Ajax and Django

Tags: django, ajax, typeerror, ajaxform, jsonresponse

I am trying to ajaxify my comment form so that it can be submitted without refreshing the page. I have a Comment model which has a ForeignKey to the Post model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
```

Here is my template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    ...
    <div id="comList"">
        {% if post.comment_set.all %}
            {% for c in post.comment_set.all %}
                <p>{{ c.body }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>

    <form id="addComForm" action="{% url 'posts:comment' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value={{ post.id }}>
        {{ c_form }}
        <button id="addComBtn" type="submit" name="submit_c_form">Send</button>
    </form>
{% endfor %}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#addComBtn').click(function() {
            var serializedData = $('#addComForm').serialize();
            const url = $('#addComForm').attr('action')

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: serializedData,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#comList').append('<p>' + response.c.body + '</p>')
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my view:

```
def comment_view(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)

    if 'submit_c_form' in request.POST:
        c_form = CommentModelForm(request.POST)
        if c_form.is_valid():
            instance = c_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = profile
            instance.post = Post.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
            instance.save()
            return JsonResponse({'comment': model_to_dict(instance)}, status=200)

    return redirect('posts:index')
```

And for reference, my form and relevant url:

```
class CommentModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body',)

path('comment/', comment_view, name='comment'),
```

Currently on submit I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: response.c is undefined` in the console, so I think the issue lies within my JsonResponse in the view. Any help received on this would be much appreciated

Comment: If you call "{'comment': model_to_dict(instance)}" in JsonResponse you should use "comment" in success function like "response.comment.body".

Comment: Thnank you, I tried this but now I receive `Uncaught TypeError: response.comment is undefined`

Comment: What will console print if you insert it in success function: "console.log(response)"?

Comment: `console.log(response)` is returning the html for the entire document

Comment: how about console.log(response.comment)?

Comment: This returns `undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224410/discussion-between-bkrop-and-sgt-pepper85).